# Jquery - how can I get to Jquery Object's name attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this submit button.

```
<input id="bulkBtn" name="cat" value="delete" />
```

Now I want to get access to name attribute of this Jquery Object.

```
var bulkBtn = $('#bulkBtn');

//how can I get to bulkBtn's name attribute???
```

Does anyone know how to do it?

I know I can get access to name attribute of input tag like this.
But, I want to know how to get to name attribute that is contained in Jquery Object.

```
$("input[name='foo']");
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: For future reference: http://api.jquery.com/category/attributes/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var name = $("#bulkBtn").attr("name");
```

Answer (score 3):

Using the [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) function:

```
var bulkBtn = $('#bulkBtn');
var name = bulkBtn.attr('name');
```

Comment: Oh I see. I need to use attr(). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `var name = $('input').attr('name');` you can get any attributes you want like `$('input').attr('id');` for single element.